# Spring Controller Request Mapping Does Not Work Correctly

Tags: java, spring, web-applications

I have a simple request mapping that opens up an html file residing in static folder. It works correctly when the request mapping is a one part request like `'/town'` but does not works (returns 404) on urls like `'/visual/town'`. When I debug, the program falls to the desired place though. It just cannot recognise the file that it points to when the mapping constitutes of two or more parts. This doesn't makes sense to me at all.

This one works :

```
@Controller("VisualHomeController")
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/town")
    public String emergentTown() {
        return "static/visual/emergent_town.html";
    }
}
```

This one does not :

```
@Controller("VisualHomeController")
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/visual/town")
    public String emergentTown() {
        return "static/visual/emergent_town.html";
    }
}
```

And here is my servlet mapping, It seems that the problem arises here :

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: too little info.

Comment: I added servlet mapping info

Comment: if the control is coming to the correct method, then @RequestMapping is working. No porblem with that. Whatever happens after that is upto your code. how is this a problem with RequestMapping

Comment: Because for both request mappings it goes into the correct method, every other things are same but the latter code does not work. The one thing that differs is the url as I pointed out in the question. So there must be something wrong with the servlet mappings or other relating to the background tasks of spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured out that the problem is with the servlet mapping.

I needed to add another servlet mapping for the first part of my additional controller which is `/visual` as :

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/visual/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then it worked. So whenever you want to have requests like `/.../new_page` you need to define the `...` as servlet mappings. Note that changing the main servlet mapping to `/*` is not enough for this purpose.

Note : It still doesn't make sense that why the program falls into the `return ...` when debugging. I mean, if one more servlet mapping is needed, how front controller can route the request to that method? And while doing so why it can not resolve the view?